# Error instanciando servlet

Tags: java, servlets

Recientemente comencé a aprender la programación en java orientada a web services con lo que comencé con el Hola Mundo hecho con servlets siguiendo un video tutorial pero me ha surgido un problema instanciando la clase de mi servlet a lo que he intentado cambiando la forma de crearlo, modificando el xml, refactorizando las clases e incluso haciendo nuevamente desde cero el proyecto y no logro que me funcione

este es el código de mi servlet:

```
package net.lucho.servlets;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 *
 * @author darkl
 */
public class HolaMundo extends HttpServlet{

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        System.out.println("Ejecutandose método doGet");
    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        System.out.println("Ejecutandose método doPost");
    }
    
}
```

y mi web.xml es el siguiente:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>HolaMundo</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>net.lucho.servlets.HolaMundo</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>HolaMundo</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/holaMundo</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
</web-app>
```

y por último mi index es el siguiente:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Start Page</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>¡Hola Mundo!</h1>
        <a href="holaMundo">Servlet</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

Realmente no sé que pueda estar ocurriendo, tengo instalado el tomcat 10.0.14 y la página principal si me carga, les agradecería mucho su ayuda

por último aquí una imagen del proyecto:

[image: Ruta de mi proyecto]

y el error que me sale
[image: Error instanciando]

Comment: Bienvenido/a a [es.so]: haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio. Los mensajes de error deben ir _como texto_, ya que no todos pueden visualizar las imágenes. Además, pon en el título de la pregunta _cuál es el error_. Lee [ask].